# Struts and Delegate pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, jakarta-ee, struts

How can I use Delegate pattern with struts framework to separate the Struts Action class from the Java classes that carry out the business logic?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's say you have an interface that makes some bussiness logic, (for example greet an user):

**IBussinessLogic**

```
public interface IBussinessLogic{
    public void greetUser(String username);
}
```

And you use a class that implements that interface:

**BussinessLogic**

```
public class BussinessLogic implements IBussinessLogic{
      public void greetUser(String username) {
            System.out.println("Hello " + username + ".");
      }
}
```

Then, in your action class you can delegate, no sorry, you **must** delegate in your bussiness logic class:

```
...
IBussinessLogic bl = new BussinessLogic();
bl.greetUser(myForm.getUsername());
...
```

Remember, an action has a few responsabilities: control flow, returning forward... but none of them has to be to implement the bussiness logic of your application. The use of an interface allows you to rewire your application with different implementations of IBussinessLogic in the future, even using dependency injection or other techniques.

This is a very simple example of delegate pattern. Your action (delegator) trust a delegate (BussinessLogic) to accomplish a task.

Comment: i have to issues to ask about them. first : what is the different between delegate pattern and facade pattern?. second what is the good practice for using facade within struts action class, i mean within struts action class i need to pass parameter from request to business to do something, how can i make my facade more generic.

Comment: Delegate pattern allows in the example I gave to you to separate responsabilities into differents layers. It is a good design strategy to leave the bussiness logic to a different layer. It's a bad decision to send the request object to the bussiness logic layer. If you do that you are tying the bussiness layer to your web  interface. In your future you won't be able to reuse your application with, for example, a swing interface,

Facade pattern allows you to make easier the access to a software library/package. It implements an interface with less complexity than the original library/package.